# Can no longer connect to localdb after updating from Sql Server 2016 to 2019

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019, sql-server-localdb

I need to restore a backup for an assignment, but SMSS said I was running v13 while the backup was made in v15. So I downloaded and installed SQL Server Express 2019 and uninstalled the older version.

However, SMSS can't connect anymore to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

I read somewhere to add a firewall rule for `sqlservr.exe`. When I try to run that file manually, it says the SQL Server installation is corrupt.

So I ran the Repair from SQL Server Installation Center, everything was okay in the output log but still no luck.
I'm pretty clueless, any help is appreciated.

The available services:

| Status | Name | DisplayName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Running | MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS | SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) |
| Stopped | SQLAgent$SQLEXP... | SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) |
| Stopped | SQLBrowser | SQL Server Browser |
| Running | SQLTELEMETRY$SQ... | SQL Server CEIP service (SQLEXPRESS) |
| Running | SQLWriter | SQL Server VSS Writer |

The list of LocalDb instances:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn> SqlLocalDb.exe i
MSSQLLocalDB

PS C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn> SqlLocalDb.exe s "MSSQLLocalDB"
Start of LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" failed because of the following error:
Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
```

Event viewer details:

> LocalDB parent instance version is invalid: MSSQL13E.LOCALDB

Comment: Managed to get it working after deleting and recreating the instance - solution found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022742/localdb-parent-instance-version-invalid-mssql13e-localdb.

Answer (score 2):

> LocalDB parent instance version is invalid: MSSQL13E.LOCALDB

This is cause by an incorrect registry setting. It can be fixed manually, but it is easier and less dangerous to delete and recreate the instance from a command prompt:

```
sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB
```

There are details about registry editing on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022742/localdb-parent-instance-version-invalid-mssql13e-localdb) if you prefer to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

check the

**SQL Server Configuration Manager** see [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image]

On the right side you see which server are running and how to call them in the brackets.

and see if it is called `MSSQLLocalDB` any longer

Comment: Ok, so SQLEXPRESS is accessible as before, but I would need/like to use localdb/MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: then you have to add a new instance with  that name and copy all data